# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||=' on import of pdfjs-dist

Tags: node.js, pdfjs-dist

Trying to use pdfjs-dist in node js app

Steps:

created new node js app (module) then:-

```
npm i pdfjs-dist
```

package.json is:-

```
"name": "testpdf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "pdf test",
  "main": "testpdf.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node testpdf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.13.216"
  }
}
```

1 line app (testpdf.js) is

```
import pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist'
```

Get this error with the import:

> D:\dev\pdf\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js:1707
> return this._jsActionsPromise ||= this._transport.getPageJSActions(this._pageIndex);
> ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> at ModuleWrap. (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
> at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
> at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
> at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5) PS D:\dev\pdf>

If I look at *node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js* there are multiple instances of use of this operator "||="

I'm no javascript expert but from what I know this is not a valid opertaor and node v14.15.4 doesn't seem to think it is either.

Note this package version (pdfjs-dist 2.13.216) has been available for two months and can't find a similar issue on the net so guessing I am doing something wrong...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As was on and old version of NodeJS I upgraded to the latest version v18.1.0 and this cleared the issue

Comment: Or as it's specified here (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/13273#issuecomment-823524483) you can downgrade pdfjs-dist to version 2.3.200.

Comment: All same issues for me! I removed `pdfjs-dist` and then reinstalled it:  `npm install pdfjs-dist@2.3.200` and it worked well after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use their legacy build through (which is compatible with node)

```js
const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js");
```

pdfjs version: (3.2.146)
node version: (14.21.3)

Install

```bash
npm i pdfjs-dist@3.2.146
```